# Flask crashes with ValueError after user successfully logs in using Github-Flask

Tags: python, github, flask

I'm trying to modify this existing app ([miguelgrinberg/microblog](http://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog)) to utilize Github-flask login ([cenkalti/github-flask](http://github.com/cenkalti/github-flask)). It uses Flask-Login to manage the user sessions ([maxcountryman/flask-login](http://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/)).

TraceBack: https://gist.github.com/CoinGame/4a6b14d0213850b29979

Views.py: https://gist.github.com/CoinGame/22d8098ccabc255bd5cf

The login process seems to work. I'm getting the github token which lets me make API calls for the user object.  Though when I try to put all the pieces together I get this flask breaking error.

I'll admit I'm somewhat new to python and totally trying to work my way from scratch through flask and its extensions. Working on an existing project has helped me understand the framework, but I feel it may also be causing me to overlook things.

Any idea what I'm missing here to get this error after the user logs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `id` you are passing to this function

```
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

is causing the issue. It looks like it doesnt exist or it may contain chars that arent numeric. Somewhere along the line the user_id seems to be getting lost/changed and throwing the error.

```
File "/root/votr-blog/app/views.py", line 21, in load_user
    return User.query.get(int(id))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

If you can traceback where the id gets lost it might help.
You could also wrap the call to int() using try/catch

```
    try:
        int_val = int(id)
    except ValueError:
        print("Failure w/ value " + id)
```

Looking into flask-github and this code

```
@app.route('/github-callback')
@github.authorized_handler
def authorized(oauth_token):
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('index')
    if oauth_token is None:
        flash("Authorization failed.")
        return redirect(next_url)

    #this code below is getting the user by their github access token 
    user = User.query.filter_by(github_access_token=oauth_token).first()
    if user is None:
        user = User(oauth_token)
        db_session.add(user)

    user.github_access_token = oauth_token
    db_session.commit()
    return redirect(next_url)
```

authorises and returns users in relation to their github access token rather than a user_id, this seems to be in conflict with login_manager with returns users by id. Your issue seems to be that the two methods are trying to do the same this.

Flask-login uses user_ids to manage sessions and users within the session. A user logs in and if authenticated that users id is saved to the session. This is used to reload the user object from the user ID stored in the session.

Github-flask uses tokens to manage users. It saves the token in the session by the looks of things. The two are conflicting.
You could do a couple of things:
1) Choose one or the other to manage users.
2) Once a user has been authenticated with github-flask, get that users id and save that to the session, so that the `load_user()` function has something to work with. This seems contradictory though, getting the user with github-flask just so as to get the users id so you can get the user again with flask-login.

Comment: This code seems to be part of the original microblog. I believe the id is referring to primary key that is generated when a user is added to the database. In the model view it seems to be an integer. I'm adding the user to the database after login, so I'm a bit confused why this is returning none after they are logged in.

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/master/app/models.py#L24

Here is the user model view for the microblog, but mine isn't too different. I can post it if it helps.

Comment: sorry yes my bad, im mixing up the id with the token. Can you track the user id - what is being passed into the `load_user()` function when its being called.

Comment: I will try to figure that out and get back to you shortly. Thank you.

Comment: Well there indeed seems to be an issue with the value being provided to the user_loader. Flask-Login requires that the user model has a get_id method to pull the primary key of the user.

When i grab the user object from the python command line and try to invoke the user_id method it doesn't seem to output the value. Just seems to be some general message that this is a definition. What is also interesting is that if I remove the int() around id it doesn't give an error, but it doesn't seem to keep the user logged in.

Comment: I have to try and login again if I want to access any secured resources, but since the user doesn't stay logged in nothing happens. Though I can see all the github data i'm trying to pull successfully gets dumped into that database and the user exists.

Comment: does this just happen with the git login? can you login with the other methods used in the tutorial?

Comment: well I've removed them from my implementation, but yes it was working with the existing logins before I attempted to use github only.

Comment: Currently trying to get some results from your try/catch suggestion. Hopefully that will lead me to the exact issue.

Comment: it might have something to do with the login manager - lm = `LoginManager() lm.init_app(app)` it doesnt look like this is used in the git examples, that git takes the place of the login manager. Have you tried removing the login manager and the `load_user()` method and just using the github approach https://github-flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: the github example doesn't have it because it's not using the flask-login extension which is part of my setup to manage the user sessions.

http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works

it's required as part of flask-login I believe

Comment: added an edit to my answer. github flask and load_user() are conflicting. github is getting user by access token where load_user() is trying to do it by id.

Comment: Removing load_user() causes a new error.

https://gist.github.com/CoinGame/f0d690b18ec94fda5ee7

Comment: I'm still digging through all this. I agree that there may be somewhat of a conflict that is right in front of my face, but I'm unable to pinpoint it at the moment.

Comment: the conflict is that flask-login uses ids in the session to validate users, whilst github-flask uses tokens. When a user goes to a page having logged in with github there is no user_id in the session so flask-login thinks they are not authenticated.

Comment: Ohhhh that makes sense! sorry, it didn't click until you explained it that way for some reason. Let me see if I can work around this.

Comment: this might be of some help - https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-login-using-request-loader